# Get rid of VMWare Workstation (installed with VMware's installer)

Tags: software-uninstall

I was attempting to uninstall VM Ware software and the process wasn't entirely successful. See screenshot.
[image]

The application no longer works. When I click on launch nothing happens. It just left behind some left over I suppose.
When I go to dash the software is still listed.
Any suggestion how to remove it completely. Perhaps using terminal ?

Comment: What method did you use to install it in the first place?

Comment: I built it from source. I downloaded it as .sh script.

Comment: Look at your script and your README and your makefile for what got installed where. Sometimes you can do `make uninstall`, sometimes not. If not, then it's poring through the script and makefile, and manual rm-ing stuff all over your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VMware Workstation isn't installed by the package manager, it's installed by VMware installation binaries.

The installer bundle installs `vmware-installer` alongside all the other components.  You use this to uninstall VMware components installed by their bundle.

Specifically, you would use this, and address any prompts it shows according to whatever those prompts are:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation
```

That should uninstall VMware Workstation.  I suggest restarting the computer after it uninstalls, though, to clean out some last remaining bits.

Comment: Mate, you must be some Ubuntu Guru or something. Magician perhaps. When I ran command you shared a prompt popped up asking me if I wanna uninstall it and I just went on. Just like that. You blew my mind. (I don't know who voted down your answer)
Problem solved. Beautiful !

Comment: @MarkAlexa I'm just an expert in VMware Workstation on the computer since I use it frequently :)  Glad it helped solve your problem, though!